# Public WMS for Slovakia republic

Tags: wms, slovakia

Where i found some public WMS layers for Slovakia country.

I need cadastral and country managing layers for public use.

Comment: Most likely there are official sources. Which can be searched for easier if you're speaking Slovakian. Or ask at OpenData.SE, which is more suited for this question.

Comment: have you tried https://www.europeandataportal.eu/sk/homepage ?

Comment: i cannot find wms layers on europeandataportal.eu/sk/homepage page

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can check those links:

https://www.geoportal.sk/sk/geoportal.html
http://geo.enviroportal.sk/aplikacie https://www.katasterportal.sk/kapor/changeLanguageAction.do 
.